# Why is my React app crashing (due to Redux) when launched on Chrome Incognito?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, redux

I've been experiencing an issue working with React/Redux. Specifically, when I open my app on (Google) Chrome, it works just fine under the browser's normal mode. However, doing so in Incognito crashes the app. I am not sure what is happening, but the culprit here seems to be Redux-related. The error message(s) are rather vague and, thus, unhelpful.

Below are code snippets to a newly bootstrapped app (create-react-app) with literally nothing added other than the basic redux connection. I've also linked an image showing the error(s).

**Project's entry file (index.js)**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

// Stylesheets
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';

// Main App
import App from './components/App';

// Store config
import configureStore from './store';

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}> 
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Store config**

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

import rootReducer from './reducers';

function configureStore() {
  return {
    ...createStore(
      rootReducer,
      compose(
        applyMiddleware(logger, thunk),
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
      )
    ),
  };
}

export default configureStore;
```

**Root reducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as reduxFormReducer } from 'redux-form';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  form: reduxFormReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**App Component**

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      App
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Errors in Chrome Incognito**

[image]

Comment: What value will `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()` resolve to if `__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__` doesn't exist on `window`? See e.g. https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/2359 for alternatives.

Comment: @jonrsharpe My god! I'm dumb. I had disallowed the use of, among others, the Redux Devtools extension on Chrome Incognito. It's alright now. Thanks.